# Python List 1 to 500

Tags: python

Can i make a list like I wanna have the 0 element 1 and the last element 500:

l = [1 ---> till 500]

I doesent want to make it like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 --> go on till 500. Is there a way to maybe do like this:

l = [1 >>> 500]

Answer (score 6):

```
range(1, 501)
```

Python 3:

```
list(range(1, 501))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use range(start, stop). stop is not included, so you need to use 501

```
range(1, 501)
```